# CSS file in vim buffer gets flooded with text on save when browser-sync is in use

Tags: vim, terminal, frontend, browser-sync

Upon saving my index.css whilst

```
browser-sync --logLevel silent start --server --files index.css
```

is running in the background results in my vim to go from looking like this:

[image: this]

to getting flooded and looking like this:

[image: this.]

If I try selecting the text in visual mode, it disappears. Also the command `:redraw!` fixed it until I save it again.

Vim version 8.2.3582

Comment: Are you running both `browser-sync` and `Vim` in the same terminal emulator window?

Comment: I tried doing both. Running brower-sync in a separate window and then also internally with vim's `:!{cmd}`. Same result in both the situations. I was suggested to redirect output to dev/null which has fixed my problem. But still I'd like to know why the output was getting flushed inside my vim.

Comment: "Why"? Because a program that is supposed to be "in the background" is supposed to free whatever file descriptors it would be using if it was "in the foreground" so that subsequent programs can use them. Browser-sync apparently doesn't or does it incorrectly so it still outputs garbage where it shouldn't and you have to redirect that to `/dev/null`.

Comment: If you have got a solution, consider posting it as answer and accepting it so that others can profit from it when stumbling upon this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the how and why but the following worked for me;

`browser-sync start --logLevel silent -b "${BROWSER-NAME}" --server --files "${FILE_NAME}" 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null &'`

What it does is redirects the output to the `/dev/null`